# Possibility to disable the property syntax for accessing a getter in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Let's I have a groovy class like:

```
class SomeClass {
    String myProperty = 'foo'
}
```

Usually in groovy is will be totally valid to access the value using the property name or the getter - which usually gives the same result for `SomeClass`:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass()
assert someClass.myProperty == 'foo'
assert someClass.getMyProperty() == 'foo'
```

However - due to a flaw in the Jenkins Pipeline implementation - sometimes(!) you are forced to use the getter - as the plain property access will not work (when using some class hierarchy), see: [JENKINS-47143](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47143). Bad thing is that the same code may work for some jobs while it doesn't for others:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass()
assert someClass.myProperty == 'foo' // sometimes throws 'property not found' error
assert someClass.getMyProperty() == 'foo'
```

Now I already have couple of unit tests for our Jenkins shared library - but what is missing would be a way to detect a property access, in short: A way to prohibit the property access so the unit tests will already complain in advance.

Comment: So it's _always_ throwing for scenarios you _sometimes_ use?  Have you investigated into the problematic scenario?

Comment: It happens sometimes and totally depends on the code executed. That is: Without any charge to the respective classes the code may start failing when some totally unrelated piece of code changed. However as long as there are no changes to the code it will be stable. (Either failing or not failing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
class SomeClass { 
  String myProperty = 'foo'
}

SomeClass.metaClass.getProperty = { String name -> 
  throw new RuntimeException("tried to get property ${name}, property access only allowed via getXX() methods")
}

def s = new SomeClass()

println(s.myProperty)       // a
println(s.getMyProperty())  // b
```

will throw an exception for line a but not throw an exception for line b. I suspect this will not be possible if SomeClass was written in java, but assuming a groovy class this could be a way to accomplish what you want.

Running the above will result in:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: tried to get property myProperty, property access only allowed via getXX() methods
java.lang.RuntimeException: tried to get property myProperty, property access only allowed via getXX() methods
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
```